# Anaconda does not recognize --upgrade argument

Tags: python, conda

I'm trying to install Google Drive SDK. I write into Anaconda's console:

```
conda install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

But I get the message:

```
usage: conda=script.py [-h] [-V] command...
conda-script.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --upgrade
```

Does conda have different terms for this?

Answer (score 0):

`conda install` already updates, so there is no need for such an option. There is also `conda update` which works almost exactly like conda install (the difference is that `conda update` fails if the package is not already installed and doesn't update dependencies if it is already up-to-date).